# Is there a way of organize file in Trash by delete-date?

Tags: 9.10, trash

In Trash I can organize files by last modified date, and others, but I want to see last deleted files. Is there a way?

My "visible columns" options:

[image]

My Trash folder screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a tag of which Ubuntu version you're using? Maybe the Trashed On column is a newer feature or something.

Comment: @Jorge Castro it's 9.10. The new versions didn't worked well here, but this is another discussion..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just go to the `Trash` folder and click on the heading of the column `Trashed On`.

To see the `Trashed On` heading, the view must be set to `List View`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you mean the trash folder itself, not by clicking on the trash icon? where's it? Opening by the trash icon there's no such column.. nither on view->"Visible Columns" menu.

Comment: In the trash folder look lower than the 'file edit view ...' row to find the 'name size type ... row'. In that row you will see it.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ændrük I'm using the List View already..

Comment: There's no "file edit view" in the columns options.. I've added a screenshot, please, take a look.

Comment: Tom, what do you see instead of the screen andruk posted. Are you looking at the correct row? Also, after setting to the list view you may need to wait a while for changes to be effected if you did that from another folder for the changes to apply to all folders.

Comment: Try doing edit-->preferences-->view, and choose list view under default view. Wait a while for this to take effect system-wide.

Comment: I've posted one more screenshot showing my folder, please, take a look.

Comment: It appears that the "Trashed On" column was added in Ubuntu version 10.10. I'm not sure if there is a way to add it to previous versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

*Trashed On* and *Original Location* are both features of Nautilus 2.32.0, which comes in Ubuntu Maverick 10.10.

If you don't have these columns options in your Trash, all you have to do is update your Nautilus to the last stable version. :)

http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus/commit/?h=gnome-2-32&id=87d96729a8f74c5255f7973c257ebcc14fb57e16

Comment: looks like it's not possible to update it without update to Ubuntu 10, sad..